# How to find the length of an iron bar when it is given as a function of its size but some constants are unknown?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm not very sure how to solve this problem, but it looks to be related with division of polynomials. Can somebody give me some help with this?.

The problem is as follows:

> In an auto factory in Hsinchu, a technician is in charge of a robot
>   which its function is to cut steel bars for a coupé's transmission.
>   The size of the steel bar requested for safety purposes after testing
>   is given by the function $B(x)=5x^2+mx+n$ inches. The robot cuts the
>   bar in pieces measuring $(x+1)$ inches in length. The remainder of
>   this division results in $10$ inches as reported by quality control
>   inspection. Then, the robot is reprogrammed and a new cut of the bar
>   produces a piece of $x$ inches in length, but this time the remainder
>   of the division is of $20$ inches. If the initial length of the steel
>   bar is $560$ inches. How many pieces of $(x+2)$ inches can be obtained
>   as maximum?.

The given alternatives in my book are as follows:

$\begin{array}{ll}
1.&\textrm{61}\\
2.&\textrm{49}\\
3.&\textrm{50}\\
4.&\textrm{70}\\
5.&\textrm{39}\\
\end{array}$

As mentioned. I'm lost with this one. I believe it is related with the division of polynomials but I don't know which route should I go with.

If I try to use the fact that the length is given I could try to find the constants. But I'm left with two unknowns:

Let's say:

$B(x)=5x^2+mx+n=560$

$B(x)=5x^2+mx+n-560=0$

$x=\frac{-m\pm \sqrt{m^2-4\left(5\times \left(n-560\right)\right)}}{10}$

$x=\frac{-m\pm \sqrt{m^2-20n+11200}}{10}$

In the passage there's mentioned about the remainder's. Hence I suspect that this is related with that.

The second part seems simple:

It says that each time that the robot divides the bar in cuts of $x$ then the remainder is $20$ inches, hence this would be like dividing the polynomial by $\left(x-0\right)$ hence by using the remainder theorem:

$B(x)=5x^2+mx+n$

$B(0)=n=20$

So, $n=20$

This leaves us the above equation with:

$x=\frac{-m\pm \sqrt{m^2-400+11200}}{10}$

$x=\frac{-m\pm \sqrt{m^2+10800}}{10}$

But here's where I'm stuck at, since I don't really know If the short information I know is sufficient to solve this problem or If I'm using the information correctly moreover what can I do to find the maximum pieces that can be obtained with $\left(x+2\right)$.

Edit: I've recently edited the question so it is make clearer what it is being asked. However by looking at the question I'm still stuck, as mentioned previously I don't know if the steps which I attempted to do will yield some result. Can somebody help me?.

Comment: @RoryDaulton Apparently it was a mistake on my side during typing the question in a hurry. It meant the quantity not the length. I've fixed that part. Does it make it more clear?.

Comment: @RoryDaulton Since it meant the number of pieces I don't know how to relate it with the function for length as it is given doesn't mention about length. What I think maybe is related with division as this cancels units and gives numbers which I believe is what is intended to find but I don't know how to go from there.

Comment: When solving the quadratic equation, you wrote $5^2$ instead of $m^2$

Comment: @J. W. Tanner Okay I corrected that mistake as it was in a hurry. But where to go from there?.

Comment: The question is not clear to me.  Do $x, m,$ and $n$ have to be integers?  Does the length start at $560$, so excess of $10$ means length of pieces is $550$?  Does this necessarily mean length of each piece is $>10$?

Comment: @J. W. Tanner I've edited the question to clear out any doubts. Can this time be solved?. I really need help with this one. Regarding your doubt it meant the remainder of the division as stated.

Comment: It makes no sense; from the given answers, at least $39$ pieces of length $x+2$ can be obtained, so each piece has length at most $560/39<15$. This means $x<13$, so how can there be a remainder of $20$ after division by $x$?

Comment: @Servaes I've posted my proposed answer. It seems that it was that the intended *interpretation* Given this mind checking that?. Maybe it can clear your doubts.

Comment: @J. W. Tanner I've posted the solution I found after several trials and reading at a concept that I was lacking. In my opinion it is logical but can you verify it or proofcheck?. I'm still a novice at this.

Comment: I also found the solution you gave, but it's not clear to me why $x=10, m=4, n=20$ is not a solution $(560 \equiv 10 \pmod {11}$ and $560 \equiv 20 \pmod {10})$

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is a matter of having that *ah-ha* moment and a bit of patience at understanding what it is meant and of course reviewing a basic concept in algebra which is the [remainder theorem](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/polynomials-remainder-factor.html) which results from the division of a polynomial by a linear factor.

By going on this route I've obtained the steps as shown below:

From going by the remainder theorem. I suspect that for the first part it would end like this:

Division by $\left(x-\left(-1\right)\right)$

$B(-1)=5(-1)^2+m(-1)+n=10$

Therefore:

$5-m+n=10$

$-m+n=5$

Then for $\left(x-0\right)$:

$B(0)=5(0)^2+m(0)+n=20$

So: $n=20$ and $m=n-5=20-5=15$

Both of course measuring inches.

So the function is given as:

$B(x)=5x^2+15x+20$

The initial length of the bar is given at $560$, so I suppose that what I need to find is the "$x$".

$5x^2+15x+20=560$

$5x^2+15x-540=0$

Therefore:

$x=\frac{-15 \pm \sqrt{15^2+20\times 540}}{10}$

Solving this equation would yield:

$x=\frac{-15 \pm \sqrt {11025}}{10}=\frac{-15 \pm 105}{10}$

From this:

$x_{1}=\frac{-15+105}{10}=9$

$x_{2}=\frac{-15-105}{10}=-12$

Since the length of the bar cannot be negative then I choose $9$:

Therefore the cuts will be of $x+2=9+2=11$.

But this presents a problem since this $11$ inches is not divisible by $560$ so there will be remaining different than zero in this division, hence:

$\frac{560}{11}=50+\frac{10}{11}$

In other words a remainder of $10$ inches.

So the maximum pieces which can be obtained from that cut will be $50$ pieces or the third alternative but keeping in mind that it will yield also a remainder of $10$ inches. Since it checks with one of the alternatives and the steps follow a logical order therefore I think this was the intended choice.

Comment: Given the context this is a reasonable answer. But it leaves the nagging question of how dividing the bar of $560$ inches into pieces of $x=9$ inches leaves a remainder of $20$ inches, in stead of $2$ inches.

Comment: @Servaes If you divide $560$ by $9$ you can also get $\frac{560}{9}=60 + \frac{20}{9}$ or in other words $60\times 9 + 20 = 560$ inches. Doesn't this check with what is given?. Of course naturaly if you follow the division algorithm to the letter you will get $2$ but I think in this case they meant a larger remainder.

Comment: @Servaes I do not have the necessary knowledge to do a proof of this situation which probably can be done by someone else who is more savvy than me on that part, but given this point. Doesn't this answer at least deserves to get an upvote?. :)